# Get attribute values from xml file

Tags: xml, parsing

I am very beginner in this and working to get attribute values from a xml document and save it in a text file.
For example

```
<Data>
<Sample Value="5.64472e-011"/>
<Sample Value="8.91325e-007"/>
</Data>
```

I just need these values like 5.64472e-011 and 8.91325e-007.

Comment: Are you using PHP or any other programming language to get this?

Comment: @SatishSaini Thanks for your help. I am using C++  to make code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attributes of an XML element by calling the `attributes()` function on an XML node. To know more about attributes: [php.net](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes)

Here is an example PHP code to get the `Value` attribute in your case:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<Data>
<Sample Value="5.64472e-011"/>
<Sample Value="8.91325e-007"/>
</Data>
XML;

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($data as $key => $node) {
    echo $node->attributes()->Value . "\n"; // here Value is an attribute name.. you can get any attribute like this.
}
?>
```

### To Use XML as an external file:

```
<?php
$data = simplexml_load_file('test.xml'); // path of XML file consists of data you shared above.
foreach($data as $key => $node) {
    echo $node->attributes()->Value . "\n";
}
?>
```

**Output in both cases should look like this:**

```
5.64472e-011
8.91325e-007
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! But if I have file with thousands of values, then how could I modify this.

Comment: @BindiyaChana This will print all of them if they are all in `<Data>` tag. So, any number of `<sample Value="">` will work fine with this code.

Comment: I can also modify the code if you want to use the XML file directly in this code instead of using XML as a string in `$xml`

Comment: @BindiyaChana I have added more code if you have XML file as an external file and want to use it in the code.. for that please check 2nd code snippet. This will also print all the sample values. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) utility from the command line:

```
xmllint --xpath /Data/Sample/@Value ./sample.xml
```

`xmllint` binary is part of [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) package